# Show result in JSON to PHP

Tags: php, xml, api, zillow

```
<?php 
include_once("zillow_api.php");
$zws_id = "*****************";
$zillow_api = new Zillow_Api($zws_id); // $zws_id is your Zillow API Key
$search_result = $zillow_api->GetSearchResults(array('address' => '7356 CARTER AVE',     'citystatezip' => 'NEWARK'));

$data = json_decode( json_encode($search_result) , 1);
var_dump($data);

print_r($data->request);


?>
```

Above PHP Code

Here is the result:

```
array(3) { ["request"]=> array(2) { ["address"]=> string(15) "7356 CARTER AVE" ["citystatezip"]=> string(6) "NEWARK" } ["message"]=> array(2) { ["text"]=> string(30) "Request successfully processed" ["code"]=> string(1) "0" } ["response"]=> array(1) { ["results"]=> array(1) { ["result"]=> array(5) { ["zpid"]=> string(8) "52932643" ["links"]=> array(4) { ["homedetails"]=> string(80) "zillow.com/homedetails/7356-Carter-Ave-Newark-CA-94560/52932643_zpid/" ["graphsanddata"]=> string(96) "zillow.com/homedetails/7356-Carter-Ave-Newark-CA-94560/52932643_zpid/#charts-and-data" ["mapthishome"]=> string(42) "http://www.zillow.com/homes/52932643_zpid/" ["comparables"]=> string(48) "http://www.zillow.com/homes/comps/52932643_zpid/" } ["address"]=> array(6) { ["street"]=> string(15) "7356 Carter Ave" ["zipcode"]=> string(5) "94560" ["city"]=> string(6) "Newark" ["state"]=> string(2) "CA" ["latitude"]=> string(9) "37.529165" ["longitude"]=> string(11) "-122.039157" } ["zestimate"]=> array(6) { ["amount"]=> string(6) "703264" ["last-updated"]=> string(10) "06/12/2014" ["oneWeekChange"]=> array(1) { ["@attributes"]=> array(1) { ["deprecated"]=> string(4) "true" } } ["valueChange"]=> string(5) "23695" ["valuationRange"]=> array(2) { ["low"]=> string(6) "668101" ["high"]=> string(6) "738427" } ["percentile"]=> string(1) "0" } ["localRealEstate"]=> array(1) { ["region"]=> array(2) { ["@attributes"]=> array(3) { ["id"]=> string(5) "49611" ["type"]=> string(4) "city" ["name"]=> string(6) "Newark" } ["links"]=> array(3) { ["overview"]=> string(51) "zillow.com/local-info/CA-Newark/r_49611/" ["forSaleByOwner"]=> string(37) "zillow.com/newark-ca/fsbo/" ["forSale"]=> string(32) "zillow.com/newark-ca/" } } } } } } }
```

I want to show result in php

```
print_r($data->response->result->zpid); // i use this what getting error
```

**Notice**: Trying to get property of non-object in E:\xampp\htdocs\work\zillow\zillow.php on line 14

Comment: is there `response` key at all?

Comment: It's an array, not a object. You should access it like a array. `$data['response']['result']['zpid']`. I didn't check all the keys but I'm gonna assume you are correct there.

Comment: i use this but did not get any result same error Try to get property of ...

Answer (score 2):

This is your code:

```
$data = json_decode( json_encode($search_result) , 1);
```

Change your code like that(replace true to 1)

```
$data = json_decode( json_encode($search_result) , true);
```

Comment: did not work for me ..

Comment: I think your expect result is very large nested JSON document,so you can limit the recursion depth to a certain level. The function will return null and stops parsing if the document is deeper than the given depth.`$data = json_decode( json_encode($search_result) , true,6);` Here 6 is depth.